# Differentiability of x at a certain point of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Is this function differentiable?

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
2-x^2,& \text{if } 0\leqslant x<1\\
\frac52,& \text{if } x=1\\
|2-x|,& \text{if } 1<x\leqslant 3\\
\frac1{x-3},& \text{if } 3<x\leqslant 5\\
2 + \sin(2\pi x),& \text{if } 5<x\leqslant 6\\
2,& \text{if } x> 6
\end{cases}
$$

a) At x=1?

b) On (1,3)? open interval

My attempt: (Graphed out)

a) If I'm right, a point must be continuous and the tangent slopes must be equal to each other for it to be differentiable.
I graphed it out and seems, that x is discontinuous at 1, so it's not differentiable.

b) No clue how to solve this. Theres nothing on the point (1,3) if you graph it out.

Comment: You are right about a) and b) does not make sense.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do part b)

Comment: EDIT: on (1,3) not the point (1,3), my bad it was a typo

Comment: (a) is correct. (b) "is $x$ differentiable on the open interval $(1,3)$ means "is $x$ differentiable for $1<x<3$". The answer is yes, except at the point $x=2$. The derivative is $-1$ for $1<x<2$ and $+1$ for $2<x<3$.

Comment: for a) do i need to also state the tangent slopes are also not equal or can i just state that its discontinuous or both?

Comment: Strictly, either is sufficient. Just think about the definition of derivative.

Comment: Well since the question gives you the value of the function at $x=-1$, you may as well use it. Since the limit of the function at $x = -1$ does not equal the actual value of the function there, it is not continuous so it is not differentiable.

Comment: For a) the slopes are also not equal because if you graph it out, the left slope is smooth and it suddenly changes to the slope of the absolute value... i think

Answer (score 0):

If u see in Ur function when x= 1 the value of f(x) is a constant

If u graph Ur function then u'll see at x=1 graph bends dramatically.So at x=1 the graph is discontinuous which implies that it is not differentiable at that point.

Answer (score 0):

On the open interval $(1,3)$, it is differentiable everywhere except for $x=2$.

The reason is that the limit of the derivative as $x$ approaches $2$ is different from the left side, compared to when from the right side.

$$\lim_{h \to 2^-} \frac{|2-h|}{h} = -1$$
$$\lim_{h \to 2^+} \frac{|2-h|}{h} = 1$$

Since $f'(2)$ does not exist, the function is therefore not differentiable.

Comment: if the answer were to only pick differentiable or not differentiable, would it be not differentiable?

Comment: You are correct: not differentiable.

Comment: Just to clarify, if a single point of x = a on an open interval is not differentiable does that make the entire open interval also not differentiable?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, when h > 2, |2-h| is h-2 and when h<2, |2-h| is -h+2?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: for example when x > 0, |x| = x, and when x < 0 |x| = -|x| = -(x)= -x. In this case would I do the opposite for |2-h| since it is same as |-(h-2)|, which is already put in negative form? Thanks for the help

Comment: Think about it like this: when $|2-h|$ is non-negative does $|2-h| = 2-h$, which is when $h ≥ 2$. And when $2-h$ is negative, or when $h < 2$, $-(2-h) = |2-h|$.